# DataTable to Excel range in one shot?

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio-2008, datatable, vsto

I've got some data in a `System.Data.DataTable` instance and want to put it an excel sheet range, directly, in one shot.

I'm working with VS 2008 and my project is a **C# Excel 2007 Workbook** project.

Thank you

Comment: Thanks, but @RoyiNamir: as edited by Antonio Bakula, this is related to Visual Studio Tools for Office, I'm not implementig a web application in asp .net. The output of my project is just an excel file plus some dlls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you will first have to convert datatable to two dimensional array, and then assign 2d array to range

Comment: Thanks Brijesh, but I don´t want to transfer the data cell by cell, I want to know if it is possible to do just in one or two steps somehow like this: `((Excel.Range)myExcelRange).FromDataTable(mySourceDataTable);`

Comment: can see funcion CopyFromRecordset in Range object, so maybe first convert datatable to ado recordset and then use this function

Comment: The easiest **solution** in order to also preserve the original data types is to use the method mentioned above `myRange.CopyFromRecordset(myDataAsRecordset)`. If you need (as me) to transform from DataTable to Recordset I recommend you to take a look [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10503/Simplest-code-to-convert-an-ADO-NET-DataTable-to-a). Also do not forget to execute `myDataAsRecordset.MoveFirst();` and `myDataAsRecordset.MoveNext();` just before calling `CopyFromRecordset`.